# Updating DataGridView date cell to database mismatch error Vb.net

Tags: vb.net

first, I would like to say that thank all of the programmers, people that make this website so efficient! I'm proud to say that 80% of my programming knowledge on VB I gained was because of all of the samples and answers in this webpage. Anyway, so I'm developing a Quality Control application for my company and there's a datagridview in one of my forms. The user can make changes to it and after that he/she has to save the datagrid back to the MS Access database. I tried everything and I can't save the date field into the database. I checked for field formatting and the database table is formatted to "Date/time" 
here is what i have:

Dim sql As String

```
    Try
        For i As Integer = 0 To dataAddemdumView.RowCount - 1

            sql = "UPDATE MasterRecordsT SET Fecha = '" & dataAddemdumView.Rows(i).Cells("Fecha").Value & "', Pass = " & dataAddemdumView.Rows(i).Cells("Pass").Value & ", Fail = 
            " & dataAddemdumView.Rows(i).Cells("Fail").Value & ", Employee = " & dataAddemdumView.Rows(i).Cells("Employee").Value & ", Gig = " & dataAddemdumView.Rows(i).Cells("Gig").Value & ", GigNotes =
            '" & dataAddemdumView.Rows(i).Cells("GigNotes").Value & "', Department = '" & dataAddemdumView.Rows(i).Cells("Department").Value & "' WHERE ID = " & dataAddemdumView.Rows(i).Cells("ID").Value & ""

            cmd = New OleDbCommand(sql, con)
            con.Open()
            da.UpdateCommand = con.CreateCommand()
            da.UpdateCommand.CommandText = sql
            da.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
            con.Close()
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        con.Close()
        'MessageBox.Show("OPEX Quality encountered a problem, Try to reopen the application to solve issues", "Error 0002", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try
```

thank you so much for your help guys!

Comment: Updating from a DGV is much simpler than that - use a DataTable as the DataSource and a DataAdapter to `.Update()` it.  The ticks in the SQL string are converting to text, which can result in a data type mismatch because not everything in a DB is string usually

Comment: I'm afraid this approach won't work because the DGV's source comes from a query of 3 tables, And i only need those fields to be saved to one main table. My DGV has 18 fields.

Comment: Try using parameters then.

Comment: A multi-table query just rules out using the same DT for updating as viewing since `i only need those fields to be saved to one main table`

Comment: Thanks Guys for replying to my post, but I think I just found the issue. it seems that the issue here was that when saving to the database if some cells in the "date" column were empty that would give me the error. So what I did was to add "Is DbNull " extra line to avoid empty cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so this would be the final code and it works

Dim sql As String

```
    Try
        For i As Integer = 0 To dataAddemdumView.RowCount - 1

            If Not dataAddemdumView.Rows(i).Cells("Fecha").Value Is DBNull.Value Then
                sql = "UPDATE MasterRecordsT SET Fecha = '" & dataAddemdumView.Item("Fecha", i).Value & "', Pass = " & dataAddemdumView.Rows(i).Cells("Pass").Value & ", Fail = 
            " & dataAddemdumView.Rows(i).Cells("Fail").Value & ", Employee = " & dataAddemdumView.Rows(i).Cells("Employee").Value & ", Gig = " & dataAddemdumView.Rows(i).Cells("Gig").Value & ", GigNotes =
            '" & dataAddemdumView.Rows(i).Cells("GigNotes").Value & "', Department = '" & dataAddemdumView.Rows(i).Cells("Department").Value & "' WHERE ID = " & dataAddemdumView.Rows(i).Cells("ID").Value & ""
                cmd = New OleDbCommand(sql, con)
                con.Open()
                da.UpdateCommand = con.CreateCommand()
                da.UpdateCommand.CommandText = sql
                da.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
                con.Close()
            End If
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
    con.Close()
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
        'MessageBox.Show("OPEX Quality encountered a problem, Try to reopen the application to solve issues", "Error 0002", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try
```